# Redux: Actions must be plain objects error - How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm encountering an error in my React Native application when trying to save user data and login details to Firebase using Redux. The error message I'm receiving is:

> [Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'undefined'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions.

I'm using Redux to manage my application's state, and I've configured a store using @reduxjs/toolkit. The strange thing is that the data is being saved successfully to Firebase, but I'm still getting this error.

Here's a simplified version of my Redux setup:

**Signup.js**

```js
const isTestMode = true;
const initialState = {
  inputValues: {
    username: isTestMode ? "John Doe" : "",
    email: isTestMode ? "email@gmail.com" : "",
    password: isTestMode ? "12121212" : "",
  },
  inputValidities: {
    username: false,
    email: false,
    password: false,
  },
  formIsValid: false,
};

export default function Signup({ navigation }) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [formState, dispatchFormState] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const inputChangedHandler = useCallback(
    (inputId, inputValue) => {
      const result = validateInput(inputId, inputValue);
      dispatchFormState({ inputId, validationResult: result, inputValue });
    },
    [dispatchFormState]
  );

  const signupHandler = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const action = signUp(
        formState.inputValues.username,
        formState.inputValues.email,
        formState.inputValues.password
      );
      await dispatch(action);
      Alert.alert("Account Successfully created", "Account created");
      setError(null);
      setIsLoading(false);
      navigation.navigate("Login");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setIsLoading(false);
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };

 
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <Inputs
            id="username"
            placeholder="Username"
            errorText={formState.inputValidities["username"]}
            onInputChanged={inputChangedHandler}
          />
          <Inputs
            id="email"
            placeholder="Enter your email"
            errorText={formState.inputValidities["email"]}
            onInputChanged={inputChangedHandler}
          />
          <InputsPassword
            id="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            errorText={formState.inputValidities["password"]}
            onInputChanged={inputChangedHandler}
          />
        </View>

        <Buttons
          title="SIGN UP"
          onPress={signupHandler}
          isLoading={isLoading}
        />

        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

**AuthSlice.js**

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    token: null,
    userData: null,
    didTryAutoLogin: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    authenticate: (state, action) => {
      const { payload } = action;
      state.token = payload.token;
      state.userData = payload.userData;
      state.didTryAutoLogin = true;
    },
    setDidTryAutoLogin: (state, action) => {
      state.didTryAutoLogin = true;
    },
  },
});

export const authenticate = authSlice.actions.authenticate;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

**AuthAction.js**

```js
export const signUp = (username, email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const app = getFirebaseApp();
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    try {
      const result = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      const { uid, stsTokenManager } = result.user;
      const { accessToken, expirationTime } = stsTokenManager;
      const expiryDate = new Date(expirationTime);
      const userData = await createUser(username, email, uid);
      dispatch(authenticate({ token: accessToken, userData }));
      saveToDataStorage(accessToken, uid, expiryDate);
      dispatch();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      const errorCode = error.code;
      let msg = "Something went wrong";
      if (
        errorCode === "auth/wrong-password" ||
        errorCode === "auth/user-not-found"
      ) {
        msg = "Invalid email or password";
      }
      throw new Error(msg);
    }
  };
};

const createUser = async (username, email, userId) => {
  const userData = {
    username,
    email,
    userId,
    signUpDate: new Date().toISOString(),
  };
  const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
  const childRef = child(dbRef, `users/${userId}`);
  await set(childRef, userData);
  return userData;
};

const saveToDataStorage = (token, userId, expiryDate) => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem(
    "userData",
    JSON.stringify({
      token,
      userId,
      expiryDate: expiryDate.toISOString(),
    })
  );
};
```

**Store.js**

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authSlice from "./authSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authSlice,
  },
});
```

Comment: What is `signUp` in `const action = signUp(`? I don't see it defined anywhere.